# Program does not enumerate in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, enumeration

I am trying to write a program that takes an input (library, authorName) and returns the title of books the author wrote.

The library looks like this:

```
let library = [
  { author: 'Bill Gates', title: 'The Road Ahead', libraryID: 1254 },
  { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Eyewitness', libraryID: 32456 },
  { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Cocky Marine', libraryID: 32457 }
];
```

My code looks like this:

```js
let library = [
  { author: 'Bill Gates', title: 'The Road Ahead', libraryID: 1254 },
  { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Eyewitness', libraryID: 32456 },
  { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Cocky Marine', libraryID: 32457 }
];

function searchBooks(library, author) {
  for (author in library) { //enumerate
    if (author in library) {
      let line = Object.values(library[0]) // find line of the wanted author
      let result = (line[0] + "," + line[1]) // store author name and title name
      return result
    } else {
      return "NOT FOUND"
    }
  }
}

console.log(searchBooks(library, 'Bill Gates'))
```

The output looks like this:
`Bill Gates,The Road Ahead`

The **problem**:
No matter what author I will input into `searchBook` it returns Bill Gates, the first line of the library. Thus, it does not enumerate I guess. But why not?

I first thought maybe I have to avoid hard coding [0] and [1] and instead use i and i++. But this does not seem to work either as it then outputs `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: `for (author in library)` iterates over the *keys* of the array.

Comment: `let line = Object.values(library[0])` also, this would always gets the first item in the array, regardless of how many loops you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. `for (author in library)` is looking up each key of your library array, instead use `of` which evaluates each value.  Since it's an object, I've named that value `book`
2. your `result` may have many values, so best to make it an array or collection of some sort, which you can stack responses in
3. `if  (author in library)` checks to see if your author is a key in the original library array, again not desired.  You really want to see if `author` is a value of the object.  More specifically, you want your author to be a value of the object's author key.  So `book.author == author`
4. your result is an array, so join the values with a newline; if there are no items in your result array it will be an empty string, which is a falsey value.  In that case that's when you can return your `NOT FOUND` message.  Otherwise you want to return all the books

```js
let library = [
  { author: 'Bill Gates', title: 'The Road Ahead', libraryID: 1254 },
  { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Eyewitness', libraryID: 32456 },
  { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Cocky Marine', libraryID: 32457 }
];

function searchBooks(library, author) {
  let result = []

  for (let book of library) {
    if (book.author == author) {
      let line = Object.values(book)       // find line of the wanted author
      result.push(line[0] + "," + line[1]) // store author name and title name
    }
  }

  return result.join('\n') || 'NOT FOUND'
}

console.log(1, searchBooks(library, 'Carolann Camilo'))
console.log(2, searchBooks(library, 'Bill Gates'))
console.log(3, searchBooks(library, 'Oh boy'))
```

Note:

- For ways to avoid `Object.values` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60665153/10408280)
- For ways to iterate over the library for only desired books (using `filter`), seek [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60665166/10408280)
- For another way to iterate over library (using `forEach`), seek [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60665170/10408280)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `Array.filter` ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)):

```js
const library = [
  { author: 'Bill Gates', title: 'The Road Ahead', libraryID: 1254 },
  { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Eyewitness', libraryID: 32456 },
  { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Cocky Marine', libraryID: 32457 }
];

console.log(findAuthor(library, `Bill Gates`));

function findAuthor(library, author) {
  return library.filter(book => book.author === author);
}
```

Comment: I think OP is a beginner, this approach is too advanced and not that helpful for understanding the problem.

Comment: Let OP be the judge of that, I'd say

Comment: I also think it's too advanced, which is why I kept the answer close to what he wrote; however, I think this is a good answer to include.  It's good to cover the depth of information.

Comment: I totally agree with that, but it's also important to explain why his butter knife doesn't work. It's better to tell them what they did wrong than just let them copy-paste the answer without understanding it.

Comment: So the problem is not that this solution is "too advanced" (it really isn't btw, Array.filter is part of basics), but that this answer didn't explained what was wrong. On this I can agree.

Comment: I view `filter` as the cousin of `map`, which is an extension of a primitive looping mechanism (`for` or `while`).  If this was a class, I would teach `for`, `while`, and `map` before I taught `filter`, so I don't consider it part of the basics.  Additionally, the answer uses an arrow function (`=>`) and strict assignment (`===`).  None is too advanced individually, but if you're learning, seeing all concepts at once can look like a foreign language and be difficult to follow, despite it being more concise (and clearer to those that speak the language).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of your approach:

```js
let library = [
    { author: 'Bill Gates', title: 'The Road Ahead', libraryID: 1254 },
    { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Eyewitness', libraryID: 32456 },
    { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Cocky Marine', libraryID: 32457 }
];

function searchBooks(library, author) {
    for (const book of library) { //enumerate
        if (book.author === author) {
            let result = (book.author + "," + book.title) // store author name and title name
            return result
        }
    }
    return 'NOT FOUND'
}

console.log(searchBooks(library, 'Bill Gates'))
```

- First, iterate the `book`s in the `library`, not the author.
- Then find out if the `author` of the `book` is equal to the `author` you want to find.
- Then output the `author` and `title` of that book separated by a comma.

Also be aware this only returns the first match, not all matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach to loop over the elements and add them to a given result for multiple entries of the same author

```
let library = [
  {author: 'Bill Gates', title: 'The Road Ahead', libraryID: 1254 },
  { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Eyewitness', libraryID: 32456 },
  { author: 'Carolann Camilo', title: 'Cocky Marine', libraryID: 32457 }
];
function search(library, author) {
  let result = ""
  library.forEach(l => {
    if (l.author === author) {
      result += l.author+", "+l.title+"\n"
    }
  })
  return result
}

console.log(search(library, "Carolann Camilo"))
```